# Persistent DOM parentNode reference

Tags: javascript, dom, selection, nodes

I store the following slection data in an array:

```
var returnInfo = new Array;
var selectionRange = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
returnInfo['CAC'] = selectionRange.commonAncestorContainer;
returnInfo['startContainer'] = selectionRange.startContainer;
returnInfo['endContainer'] = selectionRange.endContainer;
returnInfo['startOffset'] = selectionRange.startOffset;
returnInfo['endOffset'] = selectionRange.endOffset;
```

When I start modifying the dom however, commonAncestorContainer.parentNode changes to null. Is there a way to freeze this value? I dont change the node's parents, just its siblings, so the parent always remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `commonAncestorContainer.parentNode` is `null` it means that `commonAncestorContainer` is out of DOM. Check your javascript code for removing `commonAncestorContainer` or replacing in `innerHTML` of parents.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Turns out that modifying the innerHTML of commonAncestorContainer.parentNode itself also sets the property to null.